# How to sync perforce client to reduced p4 client specs?

Tags: perforce, perforce-client-spec

I have a large perforce client already synced. I realized that I'll only be working on a sub directory of the larger root folder I synced to.

Old p4 client specs

```
//Depot/largeFolder/... //Clinet/largeFolder/...
```

New p4 client

```
//Depot/largeFolder/samllSubDir/... //Clinet/largeFolder/smallSubDir/...
```

Now when I perform a `p4 sync` perforce doesn't remove the other folders which I don't want in my client.
I'm hesitant to do a `p4 sync -f` since I have files edited in the `/largeFolder/smallSubDir/`. I don't want them to get reset.

What is the right way to sync my client so that the other folders which are not in the new mapping are removed?

Note: My real mapping is complicated and deleting folders by hand is not realistic.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In the typical case, re-syncing a narrowed client will indeed remove the unmapped files.  You don't say what happens when you try to do a sync (are there error messages?), so I can't say for certain what's going on, but these are the two first possibilities that come to mind:

- Opened files will not be touched by a `sync`, ever.  You need to `revert` them -- use the `-k` flag if you want to revert the files but keep your local copies, and then use the `-k` flag on `sync` as well so that it will continue to not touch them (while marking them as having been synced, or in this case un-synced).
- Writable files will *by default* be left alone by a `sync`, and produce "can't clobber" warnings.  Doing `sync -k` should suffice here if you want to keep the local files.  Doing `sync -f` will blow away the local files even if they were modified (but only if they're not also open for edit -- see above).

Useful commands to run if you're trying to debug (pick any file that's not getting [un]synced that you think should be):

- `p4 sync <file>` -- do you get an error message that tells you *why* the file isn't being removed?
- `p4 where <file>` -- is the client mapping for that file not what you think it is?
- `p4 opened <file>` -- is the file opened?
- `p4 have <file>` -- did you even sync this file in the first place?
- `p4 files <file>` -- does this file even exist in the depot?

Note that the fact that opened files will not be touched by a `p4 sync` means that your edited files will be safe from a `sync -f`, *provided that you actually opened them for edit*.  If you didn't, run a `p4 reconcile` and then `p4 sync -f` is perfectly safe -- but if you don't get to the root cause first (i.e. are the unwanted files *also* opened for edit?), it might not be helpful either.

Comment: Thanks for your response. My `p4 sync` doesn't give errors, it just says `File(s) are up to date`. Although your answer gives me confidence to perform the sync -f.

Comment: `p4 clean` might be the better option -- and you might want to reset the client view to the old version first.  It sounds like you had a bunch of unadded files that were left behind when you narrowed the client view; doing a `clean` while they were still mapped would have removed them, but now that they're no longer part of the client view most commands won't touch them.